# How to write data to a virtual COM port without opening it? (UMDF)

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver, umdf

I need to write data to a virtual COM port that I built from [this example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/serial/VirtualSerial2).

My task requires writing data to the created virtual COM port driver so that an application that was connected to it from the outside can read the written data.
The problem is that it is impossible to open two connections to this COM port at the same time (from my application that writes data to the port and from the application that reads the data).

A more specific explanation of the problem is that I need to connect to the created virtual COM port using Putty, which will read incoming data, and accordingly send it data from my application.

I was able to build this [example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/serial/VirtualSerial2) and install it in a test system and verify that it works correctly - connecting, reading and writing data from this virtual port.

I'll say up front that I can't solve this problem by installing third party programs like com0com and the like.

I'm new to system programming and driver programming, so I don't know which direction I should take next.

Comment: Create two virtual COM ports instead.

Comment: Modify the driver and allow it to be opened more than one time, so more client can read and write to/from it. It is quite easy. You simply need to add some synchronization into it

Comment: @0___________ As far as I know, in Windows, you can't have multiple connections to the same COM port at the same time. What do you mean by "synchronization"? If you mean synchronize the sequence of connections, then, as far as I know, when a connection to a COM port is disconnected, the data from it is lost. 
I wouldn't mind connecting to a port and writing data to it, and then connecting to a port and reading data from it, but it's impossible to do that.

Comment: @0xReadMe the connection is one - but the connected clients can be more. Write the driver to accept more clients (of course you physically open the port only once)

Comment: @AdrianMole: That would not work AT ALL.  The OS doesn't care that two processes making calls to read and write the serial port are using the same helper DLL, the calls are still coming from two different processes.  A HANDLE value that's valid in one process cannot be used in the other process, so the shared section is worse than useless.  `DuplicateHandle` might work, but still suffers from the need for synchronization, which the shared section again doesn't help with.  And even that overlooks that the goal is not multiple "client"-side processes, but to be the other endpoint.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah - fair comment.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at this from the wrong side - literally.

When an application "opens a COM port", that means that the application starts a conversation with the driver for that COM port. You're thinking about your UDMF driver as another application that also opens the COM port. That doesn't make sense. You don't talk to the driver. You *are* the driver. Applications *talk* to you.

This also means that you have to understand the example. It shows how to use the Windows UMDF functions. Your application will need to use those UMDF functions.